# Unable to start postgres server

Tags: windows, postgresql

This happened after i modified the pg_hba.conf file. It is currently set on trust but the server still asks for a password (even tho when clicking properties the password field is disabled ) . I treied restarting and now the damn thing wont start at all (the server that is; i have no postgres processes now). I also installed  postgres 9.0 now and it works . But i would realy like to regain access to the old server. I have also tried a solution involving resetxlog -f but  to no avail

Here is what else i tried :

```
E:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\8.4.8\bin>pg_ctl.exe start -N "postgresql-8.4.8" -D
"E:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\8.4.8\data" -w
waiting for server to start...2011-09-15 08:17:29 EEST LOG:  could not create fi
le "postmaster.opts": Permission denied
............................................................could not start serv
er

E:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\8.4.8\bin>pg_ctl.exe runservice -N "postgresql-8.4"
-D "E:\PostgreSQL\8.4.8\data" -w
pg_ctl: could not start service "postgresql-8.4": error code 1063
```

Comment: Does system user "postgres" (or whatever you use to run postgres) have write permission on directory "E:\PostgreSQL\8.4.8\data"?

Comment: " postgresql-8.4.8" is wrong..the service name i used was " postgresql-8.4"

Comment: @vladimir...well it worked until i changed the  conf file..all i did was to try and set  authentification method to trust; i doubt the permissions suddenly changed just because i played with pg_hba.conf

Comment: Check out is another postgres instance is running. This error is possibly caused by another application, which opened the file "postmaster.opts".

Comment: @vladimir i have no postgres.exe or pg_ctl.exe processes in task manager ....

Comment: this has got to be relate with the pg_hba.conf because postgres stopped working after i messed with it , without making a backup first

Comment: I must remind you BTW that after pg 8.4 malfunctioned i installed 9.0 and it works so..that might be a clue :D

Answer (score 4):

While reviewing my `pg_hba.conf` file I noticed that there was an `O` at the beginning in stead of a `#`.

I learned two things from this:

1. Always check for the most incredibly stupid mistakes first
2. Don't throw your TV out the window unless you have money to buy another one

Comment: I had a similar issue. My postgresql.conf file had a very small number for max_connections. It was set to 10 which apparently is not sufficient for PG to startup

Answer (score 0):

If the logs show that the server process could not create a listener socket on the default port of 5432, the reason might be ["administrative post exclusions"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65234135/539056), which include the default TCP port of 5432.

```
2021-08-14 13:12:44.165 AEST [19176] LOG:  could not bind IPv4 address "127.0.0.1": Permission denied
```

The solution ist to either remove 5432 from the exclusions or choose a different local port, e.g. 55432, as described [here](https://pileofhacks.dev/post/cant-start-postgres-12-on-windows-10/)